# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "("

Tags: android, sql, database

this is my error:

```
09-27 08:16:34.547: WARN/System.err(8366):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
09-27 08:16:34.547: WARN/System.err(8366):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
09-27 08:16:34.547: WARN/System.err(8366):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
09-27 08:16:34.547: WARN/System.err(8366):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
09-27 08:16:34.547: WARN/System.err(8366):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
09-27 08:16:34.547: WARN/System.err(8366):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1149)
09-27 08:16:34.547: WARN/System.err(8366):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1802)
09-27 08:16:34.557: WARN/System.err(8366):     at de.enough.appmate.dbase.CMSResource.updateItem(CMSResource.java:1168)
09-27 08:16:34.557: WARN/System.err(8366):     at de.enough.appmate.dbase.CMSResourceUpdater.updateItems(CMSResourceUpdater.java:179)
09-27 08:16:34.557: WARN/System.err(8366):     at de.enough.appmate.dbase.CMSResourceUpdater.loadUpdates(CMSResourceUpdater.java:102)
09-27 08:16:34.557: WARN/System.err(8366):     at de.enough.appmate.dbase.CMSResourceUpdaterRunnable.run(CMSResourceUpdaterRunnable.java:32)
09-27 08:16:34.557: WARN/System.err(8366):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

and this is my code of updateItem method where the database should be updated:

```
this.db.execSQL("UPDATE " + CMSConstants.ITEMS + " SET ( " +
                    CMSConstants.ID + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.TITLE + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.IS_PAGE + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.IS_HIDDEN + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.ITEM_TYPE + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.ORDER_INDEX + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.SECTION_ID + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.TABLE_SECTION_NAME + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.TABLE_SECTION_ID + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.IMAGE1_FILE + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.IMAGE1_CAPTION + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.IMAGE1_DISPLAY_IN_GALLERY + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.CATEGORY1 + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.CATEGORY2 + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.GEO_LONGITUDE + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.GEO_LATITUDE + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.DESCRIPTION + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.KEYWORDS + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.BLOCKWORDS + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.CLEAN_NAME + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.ADDITIONAL_FIELD1_NAME + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.ADDITIONAL_FIELD1_VALUE + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.ADDITIONAL_FIELD2_NAME + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.ADDITIONAL_FIELD2_VALUE + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.ADDITIONAL_FIELD3_NAME + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.ADDITIONAL_FIELD3_VALUE + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.ADDITIONAL_FIELD4_NAME + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.ADDITIONAL_FIELD4_VALUE + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.ADDRESS_LINE1 + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.ADDRESS_LINE2 + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.ADDRESS_LINE3 + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.ADDRESS_LINE4 + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.ADDRESS_LINE5 + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.ADDRESS_POSTCODE + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.CONTACT_EMAIL + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.CONTACT_EMAIL_DISPLAY + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.CONTACT_EMAIL_SUBJECT + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.CONTACT_TEL + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.CONTACT_TEL_DISPLAY + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.CONTACT_WEB + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.CONTACT_WEB_DISPLAY + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.MODIFICATION_DATE + ", " +
                    CMSConstants.PAGE_HEADER +
                    " ) VALUES ( " +
                    "?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?," +
                    "?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?," +
                    "?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?," +
                    "?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?," +
                    "?,?,? );", bindArgs);
```

I don't understand where the problem is. I looked on the code and there is no problem near "(".

Hope someone can help me.

thanx
newone

EDIT:
This is my new query

```
this.db.execSQL("UPDATE " + CMSConstants.ITEMS + " SET " +
                CMSConstants.ID + "= ?, " +
                CMSConstants.TITLE + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.IS_PAGE + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.IS_HIDDEN + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.ITEM_TYPE + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.ORDER_INDEX + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.SECTION_ID + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.TABLE_SECTION_NAME + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.TABLE_SECTION_ID + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.IMAGE1_FILE + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.IMAGE1_CAPTION + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.IMAGE1_DISPLAY_IN_GALLERY + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.CATEGORY1 + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.CATEGORY2 + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.GEO_LONGITUDE + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.GEO_LATITUDE + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.DESCRIPTION + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.KEYWORDS + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.BLOCKWORDS + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.CLEAN_NAME + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.ADDITIONAL_FIELD1_NAME + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.ADDITIONAL_FIELD1_VALUE + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.ADDITIONAL_FIELD2_NAME + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.ADDITIONAL_FIELD2_VALUE + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.ADDITIONAL_FIELD3_NAME + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.ADDITIONAL_FIELD3_VALUE + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.ADDITIONAL_FIELD4_NAME + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.ADDITIONAL_FIELD4_VALUE + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.ADDRESS_LINE1 + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.ADDRESS_LINE2 + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.ADDRESS_LINE3 + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.ADDRESS_LINE4 + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.ADDRESS_LINE5 + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.ADDRESS_POSTCODE + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.CONTACT_EMAIL + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.CONTACT_EMAIL_DISPLAY + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.CONTACT_EMAIL_SUBJECT + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.CONTACT_TEL + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.CONTACT_TEL_DISPLAY + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.CONTACT_WEB + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.CONTACT_WEB_DISPLAY + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.MODIFICATION_DATE + " = ?, " +
                CMSConstants.PAGE_HEADER + " = ?"
                , bindArgs);
```

and this is the new error:

```
09-27 09:39:03.105: WARN/System.err(8903): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
09-27 09:39:03.105: WARN/System.err(8903):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
09-27 09:39:03.115: WARN/System.err(8903):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
09-27 09:39:03.115: WARN/System.err(8903):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1809)
09-27 09:39:03.115: WARN/System.err(8903):     at  de.enough.appmate.dbase.CMSResource.updateItem(CMSResource.java:1221)
09-27 09:39:03.115: WARN/System.err(8903):     at de.enough.appmate.dbase.CMSResourceUpdater.updateItems(CMSResourceUpdater.java:178)
09-27 09:39:03.115: WARN/System.err(8903):     at de.enough.appmate.dbase.CMSResourceUpdater.loadUpdates(CMSResourceUpdater.java:102)
09-27 09:39:03.115: WARN/System.err(8903):     at de.enough.appmate.dbase.CMSResourceUpdaterRunnable.run(CMSResourceUpdaterRunnable.java:32)
09-27 09:39:03.115: WARN/System.err(8903):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: Can you print your query to log and show it here?

Comment: I agree with @NikitaBeloglazov, you should prepare your query into a string and Log.d it before executing it. Easier to debug this way. Also, if you look at the error it seems that it's a constraint fail (invalid values), no more a SQL syntax error. You should also check your values.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
this.db.execSQL("UPDATE " + CMSConstants.ITEMS + " SET "+CMSConstants.ID+"="+value)
```

i think your query is wrong..

simple update query

```
"UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME=COLUMN_VALUE"
```

Comment: But I have more values. So how I would do that?

Comment: "UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME1=COLUMN_VALUE1,COLUMN_NAME2=COLUMN_VALUE2,COLUMN_NAME3=COLUMN_VALUE3"

Comment: I think you have the right idea but newone should still be using placeholders instead of string concatenation and single quotes are standard for SQL string literals (even though SQLite allows double quotes).

Comment: @newone: You can still use placeholders with the proper `update t set c1 = ?, c2 = ?, ...` update SQL.

Comment: Sorry, but I have seen that when I make it like this than I get an error. It is: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed. Any ideas why it comes?

Comment: just print your query and run that query in SQLITE and check it will work in SQLITE?

Comment: I have no SQLite where can I make this. Sorry for these problems :-(

Comment: just check with another value instead of ?(question mark) and at starting just put only 2-3 column instead of all column

Comment: when I only test 3 colomns but with ?(question mark) than I get this failure: 09-27 10:25:31.535: WARN/System.err(9328): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed and this is the method where the problem is: this.db.execSQL("INSERT INTO itemGalleryItems (id, imageCaption, imageUrl,itemID,orderIndex,displayInGallery) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) ",
       bindArgs);

Comment: i think you must need to add WHERE condition for Update query